# How to identify IDs whose values transition from positive to zero or negative?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I’d like to identify IDs whose values transition from positive value to zero or negative value.

So, if we have a table as follows:

```
ID  VALUES ORDER
1   20     2
1   10     1
2   0      2
2   100    1
3   -10    2
3   5      1
4   0      2
4   0      1
5   -3     2
5   25     1
6   30     2
6  -50     1
7  -10     2
7   0      1
8  -100    3
8  50      2
8  100     1
9  -10     4
9  0       3
9  10      2
9  20      1
```

The results should be as follows, where ID 2’s values transitioned from 100 to 0, ID 3’s values transitioned from 5 to -10, ID 5’s values transitioned from 25 to -3. We are not interested in ID 6 since its values transitioned from negative to positive values -- we only care about IDs whose values went from positive to 0 or negative (and not vice versa). We can also have IDs that transition from 0 to negative but not 0 to 0:

```
ID  VALUES  ORDER
2   0       2
2   100     1
3   -10     2
3   5       1
5   -3      2
5   25      1
7  -10      2
7   0       1
8  -100     3
8   50      2
9  -10      4
9   0       3
9   10      2
```

How would I achieve such a result?

Comment: How do you know what order the transition happened - is there another column that tells you the order that the two values for each ID occurred in? And are there always exactly two values per ID?

Comment: thanks Alex. I have included an order list per ID -- so order #1 per ID occurred first for the ID followed by order #2 and if there was an order #3 it would signify the 3rd entry. there also can be more than two values per ID -- this was just to illustrate the concept.

Comment: OK, What if an ID goes +3, -3, +3? That's transitioning both ways. Or vice versa. Are you looking across all values for an ID somehow, or sequential pairs?

Comment: So in this case where you have +3(would have order #1) to -3(order #2) then to +3(order #3) we would only return the +3(order #1) to -3(order #2) so this would meet the criteria. The order #s are incremental for each ID. Since the latter bit -3 (order #2) to +3(order #3) goes from negative to positive, we don't care for that bit.

Comment: I think either looking across all values for the ID or in sequential pairs should achieve the same results. Not sure though which of the two would be least resource expensive--preferably the least resource intensive option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the previous and next value for each ID using analytic lag/lead functions:

```
select id, value, seq,
  lag(value) over (partition by id order by seq) as prev_val,
  lead(value) over (partition by id order by seq) as next_val
from your_table
order by id, seq desc;

        ID      VALUE        SEQ   PREV_VAL   NEXT_VAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         20          2         10           
         1         10          1                    20
         2          0          2        100           
         2        100          1                     0
         3        -10          2          5           
         3          5          1                   -10
         4          0          2          0           
         4          0          1                     0
         5         -3          2         25           
         5         25          1                    -3
         6         30          2        -50           
         6        -50          1                    30
         7        -10          2          0           
         7          0          1                   -10
         8       -100          3         50           
         8         50          2        100       -100
         8        100          1                    50
         9        -10          3          0           
         9          0          2         10        -10
         9         20          1                    10
         9         10          1         20          0
```

(I changed the column names, as both order and values are reserved). You can then use that as a subquery and filter the combinations you want to see:

```
select id, value, seq
from (
  select id, value, seq,
    lag(value) over (partition by id order by seq) as prev_val,
    lead(value) over (partition by id order by seq) as next_val
  from your_table
)
where (prev_val >=0 and value <= 0 and not (prev_val = 0 and value = 0))
or (value >= 0 and next_val <= 0 and not (value = 0 and next_val = 0))
order by id, seq desc;

        ID      VALUE        SEQ
---------- ---------- ----------
         2          0          2
         2        100          1
         3        -10          2
         3          5          1
         5         -3          2
         5         25          1
         7        -10          2
         7          0          1
         8       -100          3
         8         50          2
         9        -10          3
         9          0          2
         9         10          1
```

As Gordon mentioned, if you only want the IDs - not the values involved - you only need the lead or lag value, not both.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do this using `lead()`:

```
select distinct id
from (select t.*,
             lead(value) over (partition by id order by seq) as next_val,
      from t
     ) t
where value > 0 and next_val <= 0;
```

Note that I used Alex's naming conventions.

Comment: Depends if the OP only need the IDs, or also needs the values as shown in the question. This also doesn't catch ID 7, which goes from zero to negative. (And has a superfluous comma *8-)

Comment: This might be a use case for MATCH_RECOGNIZE in 12c

Comment: thank you Gordon! the assistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: @BobC I agree.  In fact, if the requirements were just a little different and demanded transitions from positive to negative, I'd say `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` would be far simpler, since it wouldn't get confused by an unknown number of zero values between the last positive value and the first negative value.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the same result but in rows

```
select t1.ID, t1.VALUES, t2.VALUES from TABLE t1
join TABLE t2 on t1.VALUE < t2.VALUE and t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.ORDER > t2.ORDER
where t1.ORDER = t2.ORDER +1 and not (t1.VALUE >0 and t2.VALUE >0)
```

Table would look like this if this is useful for you :

```
ID    Value1    Value2
2     0         100
3     -10       5
5     -3        25
7     -10       0
8     -100      50
9     -10       0
9     0         10
```

Comment: I don't think it should include the second ID line (50, 100), or the third ID 9 line (10, 20) ?

Comment: OK, Corrected, now it is ok

Comment: thank you @user2410199. the assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 12c, this is a great use case for `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`.  In that case, it would be done like so:

```
SELECT id, value, ord FROM d
MATCH_RECOGNIZE ( partition by id 
                  order by ord
                  all rows per match
                  after match skip past last row
                  pattern (posorzero neg | pos negorzero )
                  define
                    neg as neg.value < 0,
                    negorzero as negorzero.value <= 0,
                    pos as pos.value > 0, 
                    posorzero as posorzero.value>= 0
                    )
order by id, ord desc;

ID  VALUE   ORD
--  -----   ---
2       0     2
2     100     1
3     -10     2
3       5     1
5      -3     2
5      25     1
7     -10     2
7       0     1
8    -100     3
8      50     2
9       0     3
9      10     2
```

The only thing is, this doesn't include the following row from your desired output:

```
9  -10      4
```

In all other cases, your desired output seems to be "include only the rows from each `id` that contribute to the cross-over".  This one row that you've included in your desired output would not meet that definition, since these rows:

```
9   0       3
9   10      2
```

... by themselves represent a cross-over as you've defined it.

If you have a consistent and better definition of what the requested output should include, please let me know and I'll update my answer.